# How to get pip3 installation path in setup.py ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I'm trying to get installation path while installing my pip package it chooses random installation path like dist-packages or site-packages. Is there a way to where my package is going to install in setup.py. but i'm not interested in giving the target in install command like pip3 install packagename --target=/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

i tried getting the path of package `requests` but in ubuntu it is in site-packages but for raspberry pi it is in dist-packages

find_packages()